# Adding New Row and inserting data to row

Tags: vb.net, datatable, rows

I have an existing datatable with two columns predefined.

Example:
Column 1 = Name
Column 2 = Surname

No rows are currently in my data table.

Datatable.Rows.Add - Will add a row to my collection

Now I want to write to the current row added and column 1 (Name) with text "Bob" then write to current row and column 2 (Surname) with text "smith"

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: **[DataRow Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx)**  Also, please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a [`DataRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) with the specified information :

```
Dim dtTable As New DataTable

'create a new data row.
Dim drNewRow As DataRow = dtTable.NewRow

'specify the information of the new row.
drNewRow("Name") = "Bob"
drNewRow("Surname") = "Smith"

'add the new row with specified information to the table.
dtTable.Rows.Add(drNewRow)
```

Comment: Thank you although I get this error:  This row already belongs to this table.

Comment: the above example should work make sure you doesn't add the same row twice.

Comment: ok that could be the issue because i need to add multiple rows then add data to each row.

What is working for me currently is adding the rows first then looping the data table and adding the values then.

Thanks